# The geneology of Jesus according to John and Mark

Tags: john, jesus, mark

If we focus only in the gospels of Mark and John, do these gospels try to promote the idea that Jesus was a decendant of King David, or they try to promote the idea, that a man do not have to be a decendant of King David, in order to be the Christ?

(To make it more about verses, I refer to John 7:41-52,1:45-46, Mark 12:35)

Answer (score 1):

Both Mark and John testify to Jesus being the son of David.  In John, however, there is just one verse that mentions David:

> Hath not the scripture said, That Christ cometh of the seed of David,
> and out of the town of Bethlehem, where David was?  (John 7:42, KJV)

Mark has more in support of the connection between Jesus and David.

| Reference | Text (KJV) -- *All seven "David" verses attested* |
| --- | --- |
| Mark 2:25 | And he said unto them, Have ye never read what David did, when he had need, and was an hungred, he, and they that were with him? |
| Mark 10:47 | And when he heard that it was Jesus of Nazareth, he began to cry out, and say, Jesus, thou son of David, have mercy on me. |
| Mark 10:48 | And many charged him that he should hold his peace: but he cried the more a great deal, Thou son of David, have mercy on me. |
| Mark 11:10 | Blessed be the kingdom of our father David, that cometh in the name of the Lord: Hosanna in the highest. |
| Mark 12:35 | And Jesus answered and said, while he taught in the temple, How say the scribes that Christ is the son of David? |
| Mark 12:36 | For David himself said by the Holy Ghost, The LORD said to my Lord, Sit thou on my right hand, till I make thine enemies thy footstool. |
| Mark 12:37 | David therefore himself calleth him Lord; and whence is he then his son? And the common people heard him gladly. |

**Conclusion**

Given these references to Jesus as the son of David, there can be little doubt but that Mark and John both understood Jesus to be of the line of David.

Comment: Mark 12:35-37 could be understood as Jesus trying to prove that the Messiah is not the decendant of king David

Comment: I believe that he was asking pointed, rhetorical questions that showed he was a valid candidate for the Messiah.  The Jewish leaders knew the right answers to those questions, but, to save face, did not dare admit it, so they maintained their silence.

Comment: That's reasonable - however, if Jesus is the literal / begotten son of God or God (godhead) how can he be the seed / bloodline of David / Abraham / Isaac - in fact why would you even need a genealogy, especially if he allegedly existed before creation?

Comment: @anothertheory Your dilemma is solved by simply accepting the Biblical narrative. The Bible teaches that Jesus came as a man. It also teaches that God is not a man. Jesus said plainly that the Father was "the only true God" (John 17:3). This serves to eliminate Jesus as God.  According to the Bible, Jesus' connection with God (the Father) is intimate--and the Father dwelt in Jesus. "All the fulness of the Godhead" is said to have dwelt in him. Nothing, however, says that Jesus _was_ this Godhead. Jesus, our Example, was a temple for God's indwelling presence just as we are to be...1 Cor. 3:16.

Comment: @Biblasia - that's fine you dealt with the Godhead trinity issue., which I was hoping someone who believes in the trinity would answer.  What about Jesus being the literal son / begotten son of God? or are you saying he is just a 'man' ie prophet like the others before him Abraham. Moses etc...?

Comment: @anothertheory  God cannot be created, nor destroyed--a fact that has nothing at all to do with the Trinity dogma, unless the Trinity is trying to controvert this.  Any being who was actually created through the process of begetting cannot possibly have been God.  However, it is possible for God to enter such a being and speak through him.  Consider Balaam's donkey--how did she speak?  Consider Balaam himself who prophesied instead of cursing. Consider vengeful Saul, who prophesied in Samuel's presence.  God always has the option of possessing one of His creatures and speaking through him/her.

Answer (score 1):

Both the OT and the NT make it very clear that, among other things, Jesus had to be (humanly speaking) a descendant of King David.

1. **According to the Davidic/Royal Covenant**

- 2 Sam 7:12, 13 - And when your days are fulfilled and you rest with your fathers, **I will raise up your descendant after you, who will come from your own body**, and I will establish his kingdom.  He will build a house for My Name, and I will establish the throne of his kingdom forever.
- Isa 9:7 - Of the increase of His government and peace there will be no end. He will **reign on the throne of David** and over his kingdom, to establish and sustain it with justice and righteousness from that time and forevermore.
- Jer 23:3-6 - Then I Myself will gather the remnant of My flock from all the lands to which I have banished them, and I will return them to their pasture, where they will be fruitful and multiply.  I will raise up shepherds over them who will tend them, and they will no longer be afraid or dismayed, nor will any go missing, declares the LORD. Behold, the days are coming, declares the LORD, when I will raise up for **David a righteous Branch, and He will reign wisely as King** and will administer justice and righteousness in the land. In His days Judah will be saved, and Israel will dwell securely. And this is His name by which He will be called: The LORD Our Righteousness. See also Jer 33:15, 16 for the same prophecy.
- Zech 9:9-13 - Rejoice greatly, O Daughter of Zion! Shout in triumph, O Daughter of Jerusalem! **See, your King comes to you**, righteous and victorious, humble and riding on a donkey, on a colt, the foal of a donkey.

2. **In the NT we have the following**:

- Matt 1:1-17 - Matthew proves that Jesus was the descendent of King David
- Luke 3:23-38 - Luke proves that Jesus was the descendent of King David
- Luke 1:32, 33 – [Jesus] will be great and will be called the Son of the Most High. **The Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David**, and He will reign over the house of Jacob forever. His kingdom will never end!”
- Rom 1:3 - regarding his Son, who as to his earthly life was a descendant of David,
- John 1:49 - “Rabbi,” Nathanael answered, “You are the Son of God! You are the King of Israel!”  See also Mark 11:7-11.
- Mark 11:1-11 - Jesus triumphal entry to Jerusalem was on the basis that He was fulfilling the ancient prophecies about re-establishing the throne of David as Messiah (V10).  See also Matt 21:5, Luke 19:38, John 12:13-15, etc.
- Matt 22:42 - even the Pharisees knew that Messiah had to be the Son of David
- Jesus was well-known and often called, "The Son of David", Mark 10:47, 48, Matt 9:27, 12:23, 15:22, 20:31, Luke 18:38, etc.

There are numerous other things that Jesus had to fulfill in order to be Messiah such as being born in Bethlehem, being crucified, etc.  However, one of these requirements is definitely being the "Son of David".

Specifically, in the Gospels of Mark and John, people admit that Messiah had to be the Son of David:

- John 7:42 - Doesn’t the Scripture say that the Christ will come from the line of David and from Bethlehem, the village where David lived?”
- John 1:45 - Jesus was known to be the son of Joseph who was, in turn, known to be of the line of David, Matt 1:20, Luke 2:4.
- Mark 12:35 is an allusion to Ps 110 which calls the (then) future Messiah "Lord" of David.  So how can David's "Lord" be David's son?  This question was used by Jesus to confound the Pharisees.  The only way this could occur is if Jesus was conceived by the Holy Spirit (Luke 1:35), and thus God as well as a human descendent of David.  Thus, Mary is also called, "the mother of my Lord", Luke 1:43.

Comment: You are using a hermeneutics method that collects information from all the four gospels. In this question, I prefer a different hermeneutics method, which is to isolate every gospel on its own, and compare it with the TANAKH. Maybe I was wrong regarding to Mark. But if you focus only on John narrative, I get the feeling that he tries to claim that Jesus is so powerful and great, that it does not matter that he is not a decendant of King David

Comment: @Kapandaria - I do not get that feeling.  Indeed, John's gospel supports that contention that Jesus was the Son of David.